# How to handle entity framework schema upgrades

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

Hi i am almost ready to put my Entity framework code first project in to production, the final stepping block is handling schema upgrades without data loss.

Couple of questions:

Should i store a schema version number in a seperate table or where does EF store this?
Would i use a SQL script or similair to perform the upgrade?
What is the recommended way from Microsoft to perform a schema upgrade without dataloss?

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data migrations  in EF 4.3 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx